# UISearchBar Flashes on exit search mode

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UISearchBar inside a UITableView. When I click on the UISearchBar it goes into the search mode and displays search results. However when exiting out of the search mode there is a black flash while it animates back to its original.

There is also a UINavigationBar above the UITableView which gets pushed offscreen when entering search mode. Not sure if that makes any difference.

I can't figure out what is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

It was do to the UINavigationBar, in the storyboard iOS7 there is a checkbox for Navigation Bar Translucent. Once I checked it everything worked out perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh for animated show/hide top view in tableView. Customize `- (void)setCustomView:(UIView *)view forState:(SVPullToRefreshState)state;`

Comment: I am not doing any animating myself, I am using all the UI from apple toolkit, that is why its strange that I am getting this weird behavior, I will try to screen capture it later tonight